# How can ng test cause dependency resolving errors?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

While testing a component with `ng test` I ran into a cascade
of errors similar to this

```
Error: ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/<path-to-project>/node_modules/protractor/built'
resolve 'child_process' in '/<path-to-project>/node_modules/protractor/built'
Parsed request is a module using description file: /<path-of-project>/node_modules/protractor/package.json (relative path: ./built)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
resolve as module
<continued with other modules e.g. sauceLabs, selenium-webdriver>
```

The test is only testing if a part of the component is defined.

```
const card = element(By.tag('mat-card-content'))
expect(card).toBeDefined()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that `element` is used in `ng e2e` not unit tests. Therefore I should have used

```
const card = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-card-content')
```

to select my element. If your component is not a special case like a web worker
you can use the DOM API with `fixture.nativeElement`